# What is Deviceless connections in the Microsoft document of Net Use command?

Tags: smb, net-use

In the following link, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490717(v=technet.10), Microsoft mentioned that "Deviceless connection". What is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include the optional device name (drive letter for network drives), then you connect to the path, but to use it you need to continue to use the UNC path, rather than the more traditional U:\location.

You can connect it

```
net use /user:Username \\server\sharename Password
```

Then continue to use the UNC path to access it, for example a directory listing

```
dir \\server\sharename\
```

Comment: so UNC path is deviceless connection?

Comment: @JingHe Basically, yes.